# Can trigger io compile ios ipa's for ios 4.2.1?

Tags: ios, trigger.io

I am curious if trigger io can compile an ios ipa that will work on ios 4.2.1.  The Info.plist says it must have ios 4.3 or greater.

Comment: No if its latest xcode 4.5

Answer (score 1):

You can't compile under iOS 4.3 with Xcode 4.5, meaning that the `minimum deployment target` value can't be set lower that iOS 4.3